MAUI: Different behavior in release build
Like others also our MAUI App crashes only in release but works fine in debug. I tried every solution I found elsewhere.
(Turned of ahead of time optimisation and trimming, for example).
Also be noted I'm using the android emulator on VS2022 for debugging and testing.
The problems on our party seem to be mostly happening regarding the xaml and not the code behind. Is there anything we need to do differently for it to work on release?
For example is a scanning popup the app currently crashes when trying to navigate to:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:BasePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                x:Class="App.Views.Popups.ScannerPopupPage"
                xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;assembly=ZXing.Net.MAUI.Controls"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
                xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
                xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:App.Resources.Strings"
                Title="{x:Static strings:AppResources.Scanner}">
  <Grid>
    <ContentView x:Name="BarcodeReaderContainer"
                 IsVisible="true">
      <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView x:Name="CameraBarcodeReader"
                                     BarcodesDetected="BarcodeDetected"
                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </ContentView>


    <BoxView x:Name="UpperGrayedOutSection"
             Style="{StaticResource GrayedOutSection}"
             VerticalOptions="Start" />

    <BoxView x:Name="LowerGrayedOutSection"
             Style="{StaticResource GrayedOutSection}"
             VerticalOptions="End" />

    <BoxView x:Name="redline" IsVisible="true" Style="{StaticResource RedLine}"/>

    <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Style="{StaticResource CloseModalButtonStyle}"
            Clicked="OnCloseButtonClicked" />

    <Button x:Name="FlashlightButton" Style="{StaticResource FlashlightButtonStyle}"
            Clicked="OnFlashlightButtonClicked">

      <Button.ImageSource>
        <FileImageSource File="flashlight.png"></FileImageSource>
      </Button.ImageSource>

    </Button>

    <ImageButton Source="pause_icon"
                 IsVisible="False"
                 x:Name="PlayButton"
                 WidthRequest="100"
                 Clicked="PlayButton_Clicked" />

    <ContentView x:Name="AdditionaleContent"
                 VerticalOptions="End"
                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                 Margin="0,0,0,35" />

    <toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="beepPositive"
                          IsVisible="False"
                          Source="Resources/Sounds/BeepPositive.wav"/>
    <toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="beepNegative" 
                          IsVisible="False"
                          Source="Resources/Sounds/error-sound.wav"/>
  </Grid>

</local:BasePage>

I'll gladly provie any additional information that would be good for solving this.
Thanks in advance and best regards,
Hans
I already tried turning off the ahead of time optimisation, turned on debugging in release yet the app wont start with the debugger connected and I narrowed the error down to the markup shown in the details of the problem.

Hans, if your computer wont start, will you watch it from a far, and try to figure what is wrong, or will you start taking it apart and examine each part separately? Well, software is not different. Remove all elements from the page, and start adding them back one by one, until you will get your diagnostic what causes the problem. It really can be anything.

Last time I observed XAML related release crash, the style was defined targeting different type. So if I was you, I would check "CloseModalButtonStyle", "GrayedOutSection", etc... and see if they really match. (And check anything nested, you can be missing a color, and debug will still work). But I really mean it - it can be anything.

install some crash logging tools

@H.A.H. I did exactly that and it's the scanner (already asked for help in this case at the authors git) but my question is more general. Stuff like this happens all over the place without any real pattern and we'd like to prevent that. I heard the parser is very different in release vs debug so there might be some kind of set of rules to follow we havent found. Thats what the question is for, sorry if that wasn't clear

@AppSpedDeveloper No rules. It is like working with a bomb. Forgot a color? Crash. Wrote style for Entry, put it on Editor? Crash. Declared list of one model, bound it as another? Crash. Exercise caution when writing code. Test your release builds completely. Conduct diagnostic, fix the problem, repeat.
